# Update Excel by OpenXml

Tags: asp.net, excel, openxml

everybody!
I have an Excel file and onclick event my file values must be changed and sent to client. I did action to file by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but I can't send to client without saving it on disk. Here I found that OpenXML could be usefull for my task.
Does anyone know how to change value of cell in Excel by OpenXML and how to send file to client in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open XML is the file format Excel, Word, and PowerPoint use to represent the data in the documents.  If you want to access this XML I recommend using the [Open XML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124) as it will contain all the functions you need to change and set an Excel value.

Take a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934429/open-xml-excel-insert-actual-value-in-the-placeholder) post for some beginning guidance.