# Insert a table with images into a specific cell in Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I have an ASP.NET MVC website and my client would like to export data to an excel spreadsheet but a certain template needs to be used. All the data is pulled dynamically from a MS SQL database.

I have used this thread as a start up point, [open xml excel Insert actual value in the placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934429/open-xml-excel-insert-actual-value-in-the-placeholder). It works well for me with regards to replacing placeholders in an excel template with data from the database.

However, I am completely stumped when it comes to placing a complete table with data directly into a cell, i.e. A10. Also, each row in the table has an image in the first column.

I thought about replacing the "{table}" placeholder with a html table containing the data, but with the research I have done, it doesn't look like that would work. If I am correct about it not working, could you please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you considered doing this the correct way? Using the [`Open XML SDK`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)?

Comment: That's what I am doing. The thread I listed above is utilizing Open XML. This is the first time I am using it, so forgive please me if I don't know all the ins and outs of it.

Comment: Can Excel create a table in a cell? I do not know how to do that so I wonder if what you are trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using OpenXML through this tutorial by [Eric White](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh180830.aspx) on the MSDN site.

Hope this can help someone else.